# Where is this traffic with doubleclick.net referrers coming from, and how can I block it in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url, traffic, apache-log-files

We're seeing Google Analytics report a huge amount of hits and large drop rate on some of our pages, but investigating this further reveals more questions than answers.

For instance, one page is reported to have over 1000 hits this month, but in our database (Magento) we only see 6 hits.

When I look into the Apache access log, I do see many GETs for this URL, but they all have a referrer like this:

`http://dp.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?client=dp-oversee17_3ph_xml&channel=001071&hl=en&adtest=off&max_radlink_len=20&r=m&fexp=21404&domain_name=hcartoon.com&optimize_terms=off&terms=Cartoon%2C%20Flash%20Animation%2C%20Caricature%2C%20Cartoon%20Picture%2C%20Free%20Animated%20Ecards%2C%20Cartoon%20Animation%2C%20Funny%20Posters%2C%20Cartoon%20Clip%20Art%2C%20Cartoonist%2C%20Toons%2C%20Cartoonist%2C%20Toons%2C%20Funny%20Picture%2C%20Cartoon%20Posters%2C%20Caricatures%2C%20Cartoonists%2C%20Toon%2C%20Business%20Cartoons&drid=as-drid-`

And it goes on...  I'm assuming it is a feeble attempt to DDoS, but that's not the question, I'll save that for a different SE.

Could this be skewing our Google Analytics numbers?  If so, how can we sanitize Google Analytics so that these types of GETs aren't counted?

EDIT: We do not use AdWords.  We do have an AdWords account set up but have never utilized it.  I traced the logged IP addresses to various places outside the U.S. like  Sri Lanka, Taiwan, ...ad nauseam.

EDIT 2: All of the GET requests seem to have a `?gclid=` in the URL.  I'm beginning to wonder if there's some black-hat SEO aimed at making us think our metrics are bad so we'll hire one of them.  We do get SEO spam all the time...  Regardless, still looking for a way to filter past Google Analytics data.

Comment: Do you have a Google Adwords account?

Comment: What are the IP addresses/domain name? These can be checked to see if it is actually Google or DoubleClick.

Comment: @closetnoc I traced some of the logged IPs, and they're from all over asia and eastern Europe for the most part.  That's why I assume feeble DDoS or at least a probe.

Comment: @Binarysurf We do have adwords set up, but have never utilized it at all

Comment: Okay. I would blocks these accesses either through a firewall or through .htaccess (assuming Apache) or however this is done in your web server. Something funky is going on, but at least I would not allow access to your server from these IP addresses.

Comment: @closetnoc I don't have a problem with that...We don't do business with the region as a general rule...  What about the GA data that is already skewed?  Any way to filter out these hits?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not GA expert. In fact, I would not have a clue, but someone will. You may not have to block too many IP addresses since most of this kind of stuff either comes from proxy servers or from a single IP address block.

Comment: These can be coming from compromised systems too. Still only a few IP addresses.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup Google Analytics to *exclude* based on the referrer domain. See this for more:  [Google Analytics - Exclude referrers](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842)

Also, you could block these based on the referrer as well via your *.htaccess* or Apache conf file, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*\.doubleclick\.net.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

(rather than blocking multiple IP addresses)

Comment: These would do what you say, but could prove a future pitfall if at some point legit traffic was ever referred to us by doubleclick.net.